sender() returns None using PySide6
I found an example of using QAbstractItemModel with QTreeView that was written using PyQt4. I have adjusted the code for my need and used the PySide6. Majority of functionality is working apart of one - when I click the button with the name of the project it gives me an error:
 ...in but_clicked
    name = dialog.sender().text()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Any suggection how can I correct it?
The full code is here:
from PySide6 import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QApplication, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton
import random

HORIZONTAL_HEADERS = ("Project", "Folder")


class PrjCollection(list):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrjCollection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_prj(self, *args, **kwargs):
        p = Prj(*args, **kwargs)
        self.append(p)
        return p

class Prj(object):
    def __init__(self, name, folder):
        self.folder = folder
        self.name = name
        self.number = random.randint(0, 100)

    def __repr__(self):
        print(self.number)
        return "PROJECT - %s %s" % (self.name, self.folder)


class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, project, header, parent_item):
        self.project = project
        self.parent_item = parent_item
        self.header = header
        self.children = []

    def add_child(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def child(self, row):
        return self.children[row]

    def child_count(self):
        return len(self.children)

    def column_count(self):
        return 1

    def data(self, column):
        if self.project == None:
            if column == 0:
                # return QtCore.QVariant(self.header)
                return self.header
            if column == 1:
                # return QtCore.QVariant("")
                return ""
        else:
            if column == 0:
                # return QtCore.QVariant(self.project.name)
                return self.project.name
            if column == 1:
                # return QtCore.QVariant(self.project.folder)
                return self.project.folder
        # return QtCore.QVariant()
        return None

    def parent(self):
        return self.parent_item

    def row(self):
        if self.parent_item:
            return self.parent_item.children.index(self)
        return 0


class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, projects, parent=None):
        super(TreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.projects = projects or []
        self.root_item = TreeItem(None, "All", None)
        self.parents = {0: self.root_item}
        self.setup_model_data()

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        if parent and parent.isValid():
            return parent.internalPointer().column_count()
        else:
            return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            # return QtCore.QVariant()
            return None
        item = index.internalPointer()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return item.data(index.column())
        if role == QtCore.Qt.UserRole:
            if item:
                return item.project

        # return QtCore.QVariant()
        return None

    def headerData(self, column, orientation, role):
        if (orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and
                role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
            try:
                # return QtCore.QVariant(HORIZONTAL_HEADERS[column])
                return HORIZONTAL_HEADERS[column]
            except IndexError:
                pass
        # return QtCore.QVariant()
        return None

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        if not parent.isValid():
            parentItem = self.root_item
        else:
            parentItem = parent.internalPointer()

        childItem = parentItem.child(row)
        if childItem:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, childItem)
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        childItem = index.internalPointer()
        if not childItem:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        parentItem = childItem.parent()

        if parentItem == self.root_item:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.column() > 0:
            return 0
        if not parent.isValid():
            p_Item = self.root_item
        else:
            p_Item = parent.internalPointer()
        return p_Item.child_count()

    def setup_model_data(self):
        for project in self.projects:
            folder = project.folder
            if folder not in self.parents:
                newparent = TreeItem(None, folder, self.root_item)
                self.root_item.add_child(newparent)
                self.parents[folder] = newparent

            parentItem = self.parents[folder]
            newItem = TreeItem(project, "", parentItem)
            parentItem.add_child(newItem)

    def searchModel(self, project):
        def searchNode(node):
            for child in node.children:
                if project == child.project:
                    index = self.createIndex(child.row(), 0, child)
                    return index

                if child.child_count() > 0:
                    result = searchNode(child)
                    if result:
                        return result

        retarg = searchNode(self.parents[0])
        return retarg

    def find_GivenName(self, name):
        app = None
        for project in self.projects:
            if project.name == name:
                app = project
                break
        if app != None:
            index = self.searchModel(app)
            return (True, index)
        return (False, None)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def but_clicked():
        name = dialog.sender().text()
        print("BUTTON CLICKED:", name)
        result, index = model.find_GivenName(name)
        if result:
            if index:
                tv.setCurrentIndex(index)
                return
        tv.clearSelection()

    app = QApplication([])

    prj_col = PrjCollection()

    for name, folder in (("Project1", "Folder1"),
                         ("Project2", "Folder1"), ("Project11", "Folder2")):
        prj_col.create_prj(name, folder)

    model = TreeModel(prj_col)

    dialog = QDialog()

    dialog.setMinimumSize(300, 150)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)

    tv = QTreeView(dialog)
    tv.setModel(model)
    tv.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
    layout.addWidget(tv)

    label = QLabel("Search for the following project")
    layout.addWidget(label)

    buts = []
    frame = QFrame(dialog)
    layout2 = QHBoxLayout(frame)

    for project in model.projects:
        but = QPushButton(project.name, frame)
        buts.append(but)
        layout2.addWidget(but)
        but.clicked.connect(but_clicked)

    layout.addWidget(frame)

    dialog.exec()

    app.closeAllWindows()


sender() works only when the signal receiver is a QObject and it's called from the same receiver. In your case, the receiver is a simple function, so sender() of the dialog obviously returns None because nothing was sent to it. Subclass QDialog and add all elements in there, then properly implement a method for that and you'll be able to get the correct sender.
